# ASP.NET convert string to pre-defined length string

Tags: asp.net, hash

Here at work we are converting over to a new payment system which allows only a maximum of 7 characters in the product code. The product codes we are using can and will excede 7 characters (changing would require changing past orders so changing the codes is out of the question).

The product code for us is the event code (ie ccsws2011), the old system allowed us to pass the entire event code in, whereas the new system is limiting us to only 7 characters. I do not want to do a look up table at all. I want to be able to create a product code list for the system (outside the website) and then have the code within the website automatically convert our event code to the product code I created outside the website and pass it to the payment system.

Is there a way to hash our product code into a 7 character product code for the new system?

I.E.:

our product code: ccsws2011
Hashed product code: xxxxxxx

Comment: If all else fails, you can go with a lookup table that relates the two product codes, and then feed your payment system a custom view that shows the old codes as some unique 7-character-max code.

Comment: I think we will need more parameters to give you a good answer.
Who is going to see this new code?  If no customers or internal Reps need to see the new code then the solution is much easier.

Comment: no one is going to see the codes. The old system allowed for up to 15 characters and thew new system allows only up to 7, backward i know but I have no control over that

Comment: yes I do. I want to basically convert our event code into a 7 character product code that is predefined for setup within the payment system and tehn have the web code dynamically convert our event code into the same product code found on the payment system.

Comment: And just to confirm, its okay that this will be a one-way only transformation. `ccsws2011` will convert to `xxxxxxx` but you won't be able to perform the reverse, right? Also, this is only for legacy products so you could run whatever hashing algorithm we give you on those to check for collisions, right? All future ones will just use the 7 character version?

Comment: If that's right I would recommend just picking a standard algorithm like MD5 or one of the SHA's and just truncating up to the first 7 letters. Absolutely not secure but you don't have that requirement.

Comment: No all product codes need to be converted to 7 characters, I cannot truncate anything. If this is impossible then I will scrap it all

Comment: This is not impossible just trying to help get the best solution for you. Is there already a primary key that is an int value for the product code table? If so I would store that since its a 1 to 1. If not you could do some simple compression by converting the codes to numeric values based on the allowed values of your event code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your efforts everyone, another value was decided upon to be used for the item code which nullified this issue. Thank you again everyone